# How to convert X509 certificate and private key in PEM format to GPG format?

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, x509, gnupg, pem

I have an X509 certificate (chain) and private key in PEM format. I need to convert them to GPG format so I can use them for signing. How can I do that?

I tried gpgsm, but the keys still don't appear on gpg list of keys.

Please, advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s separate key storage: `gpg` has `~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg`, `gpgsm` has `~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx`

So keys added with `gpgsm` aren’t usable with `gpg`; `gpg` doesn’t read `~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx`.

To see they keys you added with `gpgsm`, use `gpgsm --list-keys`. And to create ciphertext from those `gpgsm` keys, use `gpgsm --encrypt`. And so on. It’s a completely separate tool from `gpg`.

As far as importing X.509 stuff for use by `gpg`, GnuPG doesn’t provide a way to do that. There’s nothing in the OpenPGP standard about it, so there’s no interoperable way to do it.

But the commercial (Symantec) PGP Desktop tool has some way of doing it, so if you can get ahold of a copy of PGP Desktop, I guess you could use that to import your X.509 stuff into PGP Desktop’s key storage, then export it as a `.gpg`/`.asc` file, then run `gpg --import` on that.

Answer (score 8):

From [my article](https://www.pengdows.com/2020/06/27/convert-a-x-509-pki-certificate-to-gpg/)

### Steps

1. Break the `pfx` (p12) into `pem` files that can be used.  For some reason, GPG can't handle standard encoding.

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -in sectigo.pfx  -nokeys -out gpg-certs.pem
   openssl pkcs12 -in sectigo.pfx -nocerts -out gpg-key.pem
   ```
2. Combine the keys into something GPG recognizes

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in gpg-certs.pem -inkey gpg-key.pem -out gpg-key.p12
   ```
3. Import into GPG

   ```
   gpgsm --import gpg-key.p12
   ```
4. At this point we have the `p12` imported, and we can see it in Kleopatra, but we can’t use it for PGP operations.

   ```
   cat gpg-key.pem | PEM2OPENPGP_USAGE_FLAGS=authenticate pem2openpgp "Your Name <your@email.address>" > key.pgp
   ```
5. Now!!!! We have a `pgp` key, and when you import the `key.pgp` into GPG it will absolutely have the same key as your certificate.

   ```
   gpg --import key.pgp
   ```

Comment: These steps are clear and useful. The formatting of your answer, however, made it incredibly difficult to parse and understand. I've edited your answer to be more readable by putting steps into a numbered list, and commands into code blocks. Please review my edits both to make sure they're consistent with your expectations, but also to learn how to format via markdown on Stack Overflow.